# Kernel Extension Not Loaded

Tags: macos, kernel, darwin, kernel-extension

I built a self-made kernel extension (named `KAuthTest.kext`) and would like to test it out. So in a VM running macOS 10.12.3, I did the followings:

- disable SIP by running `csrutil disable` in recovery mode, and reboot.
- disable kext signing check by running `sudo nvram kext-dev-mode=1` and reboot
- give it permission: `sudo chown -R root:wheel KAuthTest.kext`

Then I load it using `sudo kextload KAuthTest.kext`.

However,

1. in the system log, I didn't see the log from its start function
2. when I run `kextstat | grep -v com.apple` to see all third party kexts, I didn't see my kernel extension.

So did I miss something? How I can successfully load this into the kernel?

Note:

1. `kextutil -n -print-diagnostics KAuthTest.kext` gives this:

   > Diagnostics for KAuthTest.kext:
   >   Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
   >   KAuthTest.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).
2. I did try rebooting, but still no luck
3. If it matters, [here](https://gist.github.com/hkalexling/03c29ffddb1cf414f03f4c33c1b23bd8)'s the source code for the kext

Comment: `$ sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"` [# Has No Effect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/KernelExtensions/KernelExtensions.html) ...

Comment: @l'L'l ohh thanks for pointing out! My problem still exists tho :<

Comment: Is your `kext` codesigned by chance?

Comment: @l'L'l, nope, but I don't think it matters since I've disabled SIP, right? As Apple states [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/KernelExtensions/KernelExtensions.html): "You can build unsigned kexts for internal testing, and disable System Integrity Protection on your test systems to allow unsigned kexts to load. "

Comment: Well, according to the docs that's correct, although I've heard conflicting information from Apple devs... "All kexts must be signed and must live in `/Library/Extensions` since El Capitan. Only unsigned kexts could ever be in `/System/Library/Extensions`, but unsigned kexts are no longer allowed to load.", that coming from here: https://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2016/Jun/msg00010.html. So I'm guessing that it does need to be codesigned.

Comment: I was just following up to see if you ever resolved this issue?

Comment: @l'L'l It was a side project and I eventually gave up this idea. I don't want to waste time applying for an extra certificate for Kexts :(

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough info here just yet to work out what the problem is, so I'll give you a quick checklist:

- Disabling SIP is sufficient for loading unsigned kexts. Check that it really is disabled using `csrutil status` on the target machine.
- Don't use `kextload` to load kexts, use `kextutil`, without `-n`. What is the output of this?
- You haven't added newline characters `\n` to all of your `printf` calls. Always terminate with a newline character, or the system log gets confused, and you might not find your messages.

As you're not seeing the kext in kextstat, that does suggest a problem at the loading stage. If your code could return something other than `KERN_SUCCESS`, that could be another source of error.

`kextutil` should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Related to the logging problem: during WWDC 2017 the Apple guys told me that the Console.app logging is lossy and they recommended me to use the `log` command-line tool if I don't see some messages.

Comment: @MathPlayer Yes, for the logging situation on Sierra and newer, [also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46745661/48660). I believe it's still buffered and can drop characters if the kernel emits logs at an extremely fast rate though. The way to get lossless logs is to use the kprintf (Firewire or serial port) mechanism.