# Where is the kprintf (kernel printf) log on Sierra?

Tags: macos, debugging, logging, kernel, xnu

There are lots of pages that explain it but I can't find it.  Many of the articles I find only work on El Capitan and older systems.

I cannot use the fwkpfv right now as I don't have the right dongles.  My client is getting me a used MacBook that will support firewire.

My kernel extension panics my box.  Quite oddly if my coworker builds my extension, it works just fine.  I remain flummoxed.

Comment: You should distinguish between `printf` and `kprintf`. `printf` goes to the user-facing console (`/var/system.log` in older versions, unified logging in newer). As far as I'm aware`kprintf`output  was never dumped to /var/system.log and not accessible without `fwkpfv` shenanigans, even on older versions. It is hardcoded to go to the serial port, see https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/main/pexpert/i386/pe_kprintf.c

If you really have a need to send kprintf to standard log, you can do it by hotpatching the kernel to jump from kprintf to printf, the signatures are identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get "live" local kernel logs using the command

```
log stream --process 0
```

For looking at past logs, use `log show` instead, e.g.:

```
log show --predicate 'processID == 0' --last 1h | less
```

None of that will help you much with kernel panics, however, as the logging happens asynchronously in user space, so you won't get the very last messages before the panic.

A few more options for debugging KPs without firewire, which you're probably already aware of but I'll mention them for completeness' sake:

- Ethernet-based kernel debugging (as opposed to firewire). Only the test device needs wired/thunderbolt ethernet, the Mac running the debugger can be on wifi.
- You can often extract quite a lot of info from the panic log itself: in addition to symbolicating the stack (use `keepsyms=1` boot-arg so you don't have to do it retroactively), looking at the register contents and disassembly can often tell you the values of variables.
- If you're missing parts of Apple's code the stack trace, run a debug or development kernel instead of the release one. Those are built with fewer optimisations enabled, so functions are less likely to be inlined, etc.
- There are a bunch of memory debugging and other diagnostic options you can turn on in the kernel, e.g. `-zp`, `-zc` and so on.
- If you can repro the crash in a VM (VMWare Fusion, Parallels, VirtualBox, KVM/Qemu, whatever), you can use the VM's simulated serial port to log kprintf output. The virtual ethernet ports also tend to support kernel debugging if you set them up right.

Comment: Thank You!  Sorry I took so long to accept your answer.