# How do I display IOKit logging in Mac OS 10.13?

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension

I have set the boot-args properties in nvram so that IOKit logging is turned on.  For instance to log driver matching, start and probe calls, I set nvram as follows:

nvram boot-args="io=0x16"
(Remember to turn off SIP or you won't be able to set nvram values.)

I see the log messages rolling by when I am booting in verbose mode but can't find them after the Mac is booted up.

Where are these messages written and how do I view them?

Here are the values for the IOKit logging:

```
enum {
// loggage
    kIOLogAttach    = 0x00000001ULL,
    kIOLogProbe     = 0x00000002ULL,
    kIOLogStart     = 0x00000004ULL,
    kIOLogRegister  = 0x00000008ULL,
    kIOLogMatch     = 0x00000010ULL,
    kIOLogConfig    = 0x00000020ULL,
    kIOLogYield     = 0x00000040ULL,
    kIOLogPower     = 0x00000080ULL,
    kIOLogMapping   = 0x00000100ULL,
    kIOLogCatalogue     = 0x00000200ULL,
    kIOLogTracePower    = 0x00000400ULL,

    kIOLogServiceTree   = 0x00001000ULL,
    kIOLogDTree     = 0x00002000ULL,
    kIOLogMemory    = 0x00004000ULL,
    // available    = 0x00008000ULL,
    kOSLogRegistryMods  = 0x00010000ULL,    // Log attempts to modify registry collections

// debug aids - change behaviour
    kIONoFreeObjects    = 0x00100000ULL,
    kIOLogSynchronous   = 0x00200000ULL,    // IOLog completes synchrounsly
};
```

Comment: Have you tried the Terminal commands I suggested in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46745661/48660)?

Comment: Thank you.  They work exactly as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the kprintf (kernel printf) log on Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737814/where-is-the-kprintf-kernel-printf-log-on-sierra)